# jQuery find image src multiple class

Tags: jquery, image, onclick, src

This question already asked but that not solve my problem.

This is my query :

`<li>` on click change image `src` for active class only.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".drop-down<?php echo $category['sort_order']; ?>").click(function() {
    var img_src = 'c.png';
    $(".drop-down<?php echo $category['sort_order']; ?> .active").attr('src', img_src);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="drop-down<?php echo $category['sort_order']; ?> active">
    <span class="left-images"><img src="a.png" class="img-responsive"></span>
  <li>
  <li class="drop-down<?php echo $category['sort_order']; ?>">
    <span class="left-images"><img src="b.png" class="img-responsive"></span>
  <li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please fix the snippet I made to have NO php (it is a JS question) and to have valid HTML

Comment: $(".drop-down").click(function() {$(this).find(img).attr("src","c.png")})

Answer (score 1):

you set attr src at wrong place, you need to find the image tag first then add the src attribute. please take a look at the below code

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $(".drop-down").click(function(){
      var img_src  = 'c.png';
      var i = $(".drop-down.active").find('img').attr('src',img_src);
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<li class="drop-down active">
   <span class="left-images">
      <img src="a.png" class="img-responsive">
   </span>
<li>
<li class="drop-down">
   <span class="left-images">
      <img src="b.png" class="img-responsive">
   </span>
<li>

</body>
```

just try the above code still i am saying that it is not a good practice to set an img src you have to apply this in better way. hope it will help you

Comment: thanks for your code i want to change only active class image src

Comment: glad to hear that please mark  this answer as correct one if it helps you.